# Login using PDO - Php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am implementing a simple user login using PDO. But it is giving me a warning message :

Notice: Undefined index: id in login.php on line 39.

**Code:**

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{

    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users 
                           WHERE email = :email and password = :pass');

    $query->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email'], 
                  ':pass'  => $_POST['password'])); 

    $count  = $query->rowCount();

    if($count==1)
    {
        $result         = $query->fetchAll();

        $_SESSION['user']   = $result['id'];

        header("location:index.php");   
        exit;   
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message']='Invalid login details.';
        header("location:login.php");   
        exit;   
    }
}
?>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: fetchAll implies multiples rows

Comment: Use ``var_dump($result)`` to see what PDO returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you store unique usernames. You don't need to use fetchAll() here. You can use fetch();

```
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

fetchAll returns an array: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

So you'll need `$result[0]['id']`